# RDP client- implementation time

Tags: c++, linux

I need to start my new challenge, write my own RDP client for Linux (full protocol implementation based on 7.1). Most of you will suggest to search on the web for free RDP client....but in my case I have to write from scratch the application.
Is there anybody with RDP experience in C/C++ under Linux? I am not looking for technical information. At this stage I only need to evaluate how long it would take to write the application. I do not have any experiences with RDP.  Roughly how long would it take for one person full time? There are many "variables" to consider....but just an estimation would be enough.

Thank you.
Luke

Comment: "How long will it take?" Look at an open-source one and then decide how long it would take *you* to write this.

Comment: Actually if it is a learning experience you are seeking then *don't* look at an example.  I've never looked at RDP but much of the learning experience with complex specs comes with how many little, subtle things you miss the first couple of passes and how important refactoring and redesigning becomes.  In for a penny, in for a dollar.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience because my company did some work with the RDP protocol. These are some select things you'll face should you go through it:

- You'll have to work out different the compression algorithms. Mostly run-length encoding.
- Encryption. The older versions of RDP used RC4 and RC5 if I recall correctly.
- Authentication. NTLM and CredSSP are popular methods.

It would probably take you a month just to get something working assuming you'd write your client non-stop.

Also as Duck has pointed out in the comments there are many little things. Just for example: how will you handle ROP3 drawing? Will you implement a few codes or all of them? This is a little problem but will probably take you some time.

If your goal is to have a graphical remote access protocol, you'd be better off with VNC which is many times easier. After you've seen what it takes to implement such a protocol, you'd see what the typical pitfalls are.